# How do I use piano pedals in Garageband?

Tags: garageband

I created a new piano project in Garageband. When I click the on-screen keyboard, it plays notes. On a normal piano, [one of the pedals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustain_pedal) causes notes to continue playing even after they are released (I believe they eventually begin to slowly fade away). How can I get this same effect in Garageband?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> key functions as the sustain pedal in the on-screen keyboard, if you switch to the Musical Typing mode:

[image]

If you must use the Keyboard mode, you can insert pedaling after the fact in the Score editor:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to use the pedal in the other mode?

Comment: Not as easily, but sure (edited my answer).